# creating a sequence and storing the data in lists without mixing the data

Tags: r

I want to create a sequence of lists in R based on some time dependent sequence. The closest I have found to what I want is the following:

```
rBayesianOptimization::KFold(seq(1:30), nfolds = 5,
                  stratified = TRUE, seed = 0)
```

Which gives:

```
[[1]]
  [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
 [38]  2  2  2  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7
 [75]  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 11 11 11 11 11 11 14 14 14 14 14 14
[112] 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 23 23 25 25 25 25 25

[[2]]
  [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  4  4  5  5  5  5  5
 [38]  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  8 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 13 13 13 13
 [75] 13 13 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 19 19 20 20 21 21 21 22 22
[112] 22 22 23 23 24 24 25 26 26 27 28 28 29 30

[[3]]
  [1]  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  8
 [38]  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12
 [75] 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 17 17 18 18 19 19 19 20 21 21 21 22 22 22
[112] 23 23 24 24 26 27 27

[[4]]
 [1]  1  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  6  6  6  6  6  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10 11 12 12
[39] 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 17 18 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
[77] 21 21 21 21 22 22 23 23 24 26 26 27 28 29

[[5]]
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  9  9
[39]  9  9  9  9 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 14 24 24 25 25 25
```

I would like to keep the order of the original data and not mix the data up or miss any observations.

I would like to keep the "structure" of the above lists however. The closest I have come to a solution is:

```
f <- function(x){
  r = rollapply(x, width = 5, FUN = print)
  return(r)
}

f(seq(1:30))
```

Which gives what I want just not in the list structure previously:

Output:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    2    3    4    5    6
 [3,]    3    4    5    6    7
 [4,]    4    5    6    7    8
 [5,]    5    6    7    8    9
 [6,]    6    7    8    9   10
 [7,]    7    8    9   10   11
 [8,]    8    9   10   11   12
 [9,]    9   10   11   12   13
[10,]   10   11   12   13   14
[11,]   11   12   13   14   15
[12,]   12   13   14   15   16
[13,]   13   14   15   16   17
[14,]   14   15   16   17   18
[15,]   15   16   17   18   19
[16,]   16   17   18   19   20
[17,]   17   18   19   20   21
[18,]   18   19   20   21   22
[19,]   19   20   21   22   23
[20,]   20   21   22   23   24
[21,]   21   22   23   24   25
[22,]   22   23   24   25   26
[23,]   23   24   25   26   27
[24,]   24   25   26   27   28
[25,]   25   26   27   28   29
[26,]   26   27   28   29   30
```

The desired output would be something similar as doing `t(f(seq(1:30)))` but having the list structure:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21
[3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22
[4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23
[5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24
     [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26]
[1,]    21    22    23    24    25    26
[2,]    22    23    24    25    26    27
[3,]    23    24    25    26    27    28
[4,]    24    25    26    27    28    29
[5,]    25    26    27    28    29    30
```

I have tried splitting by rows also without luck:

```
d <- f(seq(1:30))

split(d, seq(ncol(d)))
```

EDIT:

Expected output:

```
[[1]]
  [1] 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26
[[2]]
  [1] 2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
[[3]]
  [1] 3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28
[[4]]
  [1] 4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29
[[5]]
  [1] 5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30
```

where `[[1]]`, `[[2]]`, `[[3]]`, `[[4]]`, `[[5]]` are lists.

SessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C             
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] igraph_1.2.4.2              rBayesianOptimization_1.1.0 MlBayesOpt_0.3.4            data.table_1.12.8          
 [5] Matrix_1.2-17               splitstackshape_1.4.8       rvest_0.3.5                 xml2_1.2.2                 
 [9] chron_2.3-54                forecast_8.9                forcats_0.4.0               readr_1.3.1                
[13] tibble_2.1.3                tidyverse_1.3.0             geosphere_1.5-10            imputeTS_3.0               
[17] xgboost_666.6.4.1           tsfeatures_1.0.1            rsample_0.0.5.9000          purrr_0.3.3                
[21] directlabels_2018.05.22     ggplot2_3.2.1               tidyquant_0.5.8             quantmod_0.4-15            
[25] TTR_0.23-5                  PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.3  xts_0.11-2                  zoo_1.8-6                  
[29] lubridate_1.7.4             tidyr_1.0.0                 stringr_1.4.0               dplyr_0.8.3                

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-142      fs_1.3.1          httr_1.4.1        tools_3.6.1       backports_1.1.5   R6_2.4.1         
 [7] DBI_1.0.0.9004    lazyeval_0.2.2    colorspace_1.4-1  nnet_7.3-12       withr_2.1.2       sp_1.3-2         
[13] tidyselect_0.2.5  curl_4.3          compiler_3.6.1    cli_1.1.0         labeling_0.3      tseries_0.10-47  
[19] scales_1.1.0      lmtest_0.9-37     fracdiff_1.4-2    quadprog_1.5-8    digest_0.6.23     pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[25] lhs_1.0.1         dbplyr_1.4.2      rlang_0.4.2       readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.10   farver_2.0.1     
[31] generics_0.0.2    jsonlite_1.6      magrittr_1.5      GPfit_1.0-8       Rcpp_1.0.3        Quandl_2.10.0    
[37] munsell_0.5.0     lifecycle_0.1.0   furrr_0.1.0       stringi_1.4.3     plyr_1.8.4        grid_3.6.1       
[43] parallel_3.6.1    listenv_0.7.0     crayon_1.3.4      lattice_0.20-38   haven_2.2.0       hms_0.5.2.9000   
[49] zeallot_0.1.0     pillar_1.4.2      ranger_0.11.2     codetools_0.2-16  reprex_0.3.0      urca_1.3-0       
[55] glue_1.3.1        stinepack_1.4     modelr_0.1.5      vctrs_0.2.0       selectr_0.4-2     foreach_1.4.7    
[61] cellranger_1.1.0  gtable_0.3.0      future_1.15.1     assertthat_0.2.1  broom_0.5.2       e1071_1.7-3      
[67] class_7.3-15      timeDate_3043.102 iterators_1.0.12  globals_0.12.4    ellipsis_0.3.0
```

Comment: `1:30` is equal to `seq(1, 30)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `asplit` (recently introduced in `base R` - >= R 3.6.0) and specify the `MARGIN` to split (1 - row, 2 - column)

```
asplit(d, 2)
#[[1]]
 #[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

#[[2]]
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27

#[[3]]
# [1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28

#[[4]]
# [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29

#[[5]]
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Or another option is to do the `split` with `col`

```
split(d, col(d))
```

---

The `asplit` can be added into the function itself

```
f <- function(x){
  asplit(rollapply(x, width = 5, FUN = I), 2)
}

f(1:30) # it output the expected list
```

---

Or another option is `embed` from `base R`

```
n <- 5
asplit(embed(1:30, n)[, n:1 ], 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I added an edit to the original post to show the expected output. I think `asplit(embed(1:30, 5)[, 5:1 ], 2)` does it. What is `d` here?

Comment: @user113156  I updated the post to `asplit(d, 2)`.   Please check.  `d <- f(seq(1:30))` from your post

Comment: I get this error `Error in aperm.default(x, c(s.call, s.ans)) : 
  'perm' is of wrong length 2 (!= 1)` But the function `f` version works great!

Comment: @user113156  Can you show the `R version` I am using `R 3.6.0` `asplit` was introduced in to `base R` recently from R 3.6 onwards (i think)

Comment: @user113156  If your version is older, you can use `split(d, col(d))`

Comment: I added my sessionInfo. R 3.6.1

Comment: @user113156  That is strange.  Are you getting the error based on the same example i.e. `f(1:30)`

Comment: When I run `d <- f(seq(1:30)) asplit(d, 2)` I get the error. When I change `d` to `d <- f(seq(1, 30))` I get the error also.

Comment: @user113156  Ok got it.  I think you are using the modified `f` I created which also includes the `asplit` inside.  So, essentailly you are trying to split the `list` output from `f` with `asplit`, hence the error

Comment: Yes, thats it! I was using your `f` and not my own.